# Register User Form Not Working ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I'm trying to create user accounts for a ASP.NET CORE MVC application. I followed the steps in the microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and it doesn't seem to be working.

My register form doesn't hit the post method (OnPostAsync) in Register.cshtml.cs on submit, what am I missing?

Cheers!

Register.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1 class="text-center text-white aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<div class="row justify-content-center text-white text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h2 class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr class="aos-item" data-aos="fade-up" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-floating text-black my-2 aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating text-black my-2 aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating text-black my-2 aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary py-2 aos-item" data-aos="fade-up">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Register.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
                                                  .ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation",
                                              new { email = Input.Email });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

*******EDIT****** - Program.cs code

```
using IntellipaveServer.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

`

Tried adding tag [HTMLPOST] above post method and didn't change anything

Comment: Would you kindly confirm that, you have registered `app.MapRazorPages();` and `builder.Services.AddRazorPages();` on your `program.cs` file, this may also cause the issue.

Comment: Hello did you try the solution? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Comment: Hello @MdFaridUddinKiron! thank you for your input, I still couldn't seem to get it working when I tried that. I'm using .net core mvc but my action never defaulted to any value in the html. This error occurs after using the scaffolding feature to add a register and login screen

Comment: Thanks for your response, you are saying you are using `.net core mvc` whereas, shared code seems `razorpage`. However, this modification should hit your controller as expeceted `<form id="registerForm" asp-action="OnPostAsync" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">`. Please check the screenshot as well. Feel free share if you encounter any further issues.

Comment: In addition, could you please share your `program.cs` details as well?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron For the reference, the scaffolded identity code for `.net core` indeed uses Razor pages even if you scaffold it into `mvc` project.

Comment: OP is using `razor page` in `.net core mvc` as he explained. However, we still need to check the `program.cs` details as the issue should resolve by using `asp-action="OnPostAsync"` in this form. Therefore, I have reproduced OP's scenario and got it work thus as OP acknowledged that in his eenvironment still not working to need to check that.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron I have made edits to my initial post to include program.cs

Comment: I have checked your code, you haven't use `builder.Services.AddRazorPages()` which is mandatory for `razor page`, I can see there in only `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();` in your code. This is ` `builder.Services.AddRazorPages()`` missing.

Answer (score 0):

> My register form doesn't hit the post method (OnPostAsync) in
> Register.cshtml.cs on submit, what am I missing?

Well, as per your code you are missing the `asp-action` attribute on your `form`. If you don't use this `action attribute` compiler autometically generate your `action route` as `action="/YourController/PostAction"` and on submit and always hit your same action which you have used to load the view.As you can see below:

[image]

**Troubleshooting Result:**

[image]

**Solution:**

You should use this `asp-action="OnPostAsync"` attribute on your `from` so altogether your form should look like:

```
<form id="registerForm" asp-action="OnPostAsync" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Update

Make sure that, you have registered

[`app.MapRazorPages();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services) and

[`builder.Services.AddRazorPages();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services)

on your `program.cs` file.

**Note:** You can [check more details here how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services).

Comment: The OP is using Razor Pages, not MVC (so there is no `Controller`).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your point @Dai, as OP also written `ASP.NET CORE MVC` so I investigated that actually, Now I am investigating `Razor page`  scenario as well.

Comment: Farid - we have had some conversations about your general posting style before. You have removed some of the inappropriate inline code formatting from your most recent posts, so there is no significantly less work to repair. I appreciate this change from you.

Comment: Two more things to consider: "hope this helps" and all variations thereof are removed on sight at Stack Overflow. This edit has been made some 50 times on your posts already. **Aim for technical writing** if you can. Remember that all editors here are volunteers.

Comment: Next, if you have an update to a post, **put the update at the end**. Consider the new reader to your post - do you expect them to read your post forward or backwards?

Comment: Okay noted @halfer, I will follow your instructions accordingly.